# Can it be a good idea to build a website out of one line of HTML and fully Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So what I did was that I created two files `index.html` and `script.js` and using all I did on the html was I just used the script tag.
`<script src="script.js"></script>`  and on the script.js file I just  typed  `document.write("<html><h...the whole html in a line></html>)`. Ok it may not seem like the best idea but it seemed more faster and the styling worked fine, so is it actually a good idea? and mainly is it faster?

Comment: Why do you think it's faster?  It's not even valid HTML.  There are many things wrong with this... but I'd like to understand why you're doing what you're doing so I can explain it better.

Comment: `but it seemed more faster` - so continue this way. There are lots of websites written entirely out of client side JS. They are known is SPA (single page applications). I certainly wouldn't recommend doing it with vanilla js (i.e. without the help of a framework like angular/vue/react).

Comment: @Adam There's certainly no problem with vanilla JS single-page apps, but there are definitely problems with `document.write()`, and trying to do it with the opening `<html>` tag.

Comment: @Brad - then the OP will figure that out. The question is "what's wrong with trying it this way" - the best lessons are learned first hand. I say go for it until you hit a road block.

Comment: @Adam Agreed on that point, wholly.

Comment: @brad I was doing it just out of wanting to know more

Comment: You say it "seemed faster" but how did you judge that? Also, from a code writing perspective there's the problem that most IDEs won't do HTML syntax highlighting for a JavaScript string.

Comment: I was making a static website when the idea popped up and since javascript is fastly executed I thought it would be actually a better idea to try

Comment: @JohnMontgomery yes it was a little faster

Comment: @bethropolis The browser first has to create the document, parse HTML up to the point of your script, execute your script, inject HTML into that outer HTML, parse it, and then build the document from there.  Vs. just loading the document once in the first place.  I don't know how you determined this was faster, but I assure you it isn't.

Comment: @bethropolis My question was *how* you judged that it was faster.

Comment: @Brad that is what I thought, and that is why the `document.write()` came first on my javascript

Comment: @JohnMontgomery ok, the way it worked in my head is that this would be faster

Comment: It looks like you should use pjax or a reactive framework like React, Backbone, Aurelia, Ember, Handlebars, Underscore, Angular, Vue or Knockout. They are designed for using Javascript to update content of a page and have single page websites.

Comment: I wish they'd [Make JavaScript Files a Valid Entry Point to a Web Page](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/807).

Answer (score 2):

No, I can't think of any logical way how that would be faster for a static page. I'm not sure how you were expecting it to work, but instead of just parsing the HTML, it has to run your script, inject the content into the page, and then parse the resulting HTML anyway.

Keep the JavaScript for when you need dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

My main concern, with constructing a page in the manner you've described is that it may not get indexed into the search engines as well as a page that has static HTML. The web crawler of the search engine would need to be sophisticated enough to run your javascript before scraping the page's text content. I'm not sure they all do that currently, but they should in my opinion.

So, I wouldn't do this on a page you want to be found via the search engines.

Comment: Personally, I like the idea of doing everything with Javascript. I like generating all html using Javascript and wish the spec writers would make it to where you don't even need to serve an actual html file. I wish I could serve a whole webpage from a single javascript bundle (without any physical HTML files):
https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/807

Answer (score 0):

There are top-notch web applications built entirely out of JavaScript, using frontend frameworks like React.js, Angular.js, Vue.js, etc.
So it isn't actually a bad idea building your site fully out of JavaScript!

Comment: This is irrelevant to `document.write()` and usage of `<html>` tags, and in comparison to using HTML when the page is static in the first place.

Comment: Those are good for handling dynamic content though, I seriously doubt they'd give a performance improvement for a static page.

Comment: @Brad I just went out of my regular zone just to mess with it a bit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can compare HTML and Javascript frameworks which can be used to build websites (React, Angular, etc.), because they work very differently. Remember, HTML is a markup language, while things such as React and Angular are frameworks written in the JavaScript language.

So to answer your question, is it a good idea to build a website using only JavaScript? - The simple answer is it depends. Using React to make applications or even static websites can save you quite a bit of time, though using plain JavaScript really wouldn't have too many benefits as far as I can see. But if you just want to play around with whatever you're doing, then I'd say sure, go ahead!